# Calculate Hourly vacation accrual

Tags: arithmetic

I'm try to calculate  vacation accrual for 40 hour week for an employee who is allowed 15 days vacation per yer.if the number of business hours per year is 2080,that means his accrual rate is 40/2080= 0.019231 per hour.So for each day,the employee accrues 0.019231*8=0.15385 daily.
My question is shouldn't the total(0.15385*260) be equal to 15 days or am I looking at it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking at it wrong.

He works (without vacation) for $2080$ hours per year. He works $52$ weeks in a year, and with $5$ days in a workweek, he works $8$ hours per day. $15$ days off means that he gets $15 \times 8=120$ hours off. So in $2080-120=1960$ hours he gets $120$ hours off. $1960/8=245$ days. So he has $245$ days to get $120$ hours off. This comes out to $0.489796$ hours per day, which is $0.061224$ days off accrued per day worked. You can then convert this to days off per hour worked, days off per week worked, etc.